# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}g(\cos \pi x)\;dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Let $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$$g(s) = \begin{cases}
1, & s \geq 1/2 \\
      0, &s < 1/2
\end{cases}$$

Evaluate  $\int_{0}^{1}g(\cos \pi x)\;dx$.

My attempt  : the  function is $0$  from $x=0$ to $x=\frac{1}{3}$ and $x=\frac{5}{3}$ to $x=1$ and it is $1$ in  between.

Now the  area  enclosed    $1 \times \frac{5-1}{3}$

Is  its true ?

Comment: So close. I think it is a typo.

Comment: No, $x=1\to\cos\pi x\not\ge \frac12$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x \in (0,\pi)$ note that  $\cos (\pi x ) \geq \frac 1 2 $ iff $x \leq \frac {\pi} 3$. So the integral is $\int_0^{\pi/3} 1dx=\frac {\pi} 3$.

$\cos (\pi x)$ decreases strictly from $1$ to $-1$ on $(0,\pi)$ and it has the value $\frac 1 2$ when $x=\frac {\pi} 3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{1} g(\pi x) dx=\int_{-1}^{1} {\frac{g(t)}{\pi \sqrt{1-t^2}} dt/= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{1/2}^{1}} \frac{g(t) dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} =\frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: A change of variable seems overkill, and is a source of errors...